# JS - How is .filter working with this callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, callback

I'm new to Javascript and am currently going through the basics of callback functions and am having difficulty understanding why the code below returns an array of odds:

Code:

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6];
function isOddNumber(number) {
    return number % 2;
}
const oddNumbers = numbers.filter(isOddNumber);
console.log(oddNumbers); // [ 1, 7, 3, 5 ]
```

I see that the `.filter` is calling `isOddNumber` but I'm not sure how `isOddNumber` is passing or failing the values in the array. Is the `return number % 2` pushing a `1` or `0` back to `.filter` and interpreting as truthy or falsy?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `filter()` passes each element to the provided `isOddNumber` callback, which in turn returns the remainder after dividing by 2 (either 0 or 1), which is evaluated as a boolean by the filter.

Answer (score 0):

@pilchard:
`filter()` passes each element to the provided `isOddNumber` callback, which in turn returns the remainder after dividing by 2 (either 0 or 1), which is evaluated as a boolean by the filter.